# Can I write a Selenium Code Module for Ranorex?

Tags: c#, selenium, ranorex

We have the situation that we already have the whole solution (very big solution) under test with selenium(c#) for UI tests (incl all page objects). Now for End2End testing we want to implement Ranorex to help abstract testcase building for Testdesigners without programming skills. Is there a possibility to write selenium based tests based on the existing page objects and provide them as code modules to ranorex? I could not find any reference or code examples to do this. We use a selenium grid for execution so I think this should be possible in theory when I can access the webdriver. But I'm not sure. Any tips or other inputs are helpful thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ranorex support helped me with the Problem. You can access the Selenium Webdriver with the following code:
  public void SeleniumAPI ()
        {
              var webDriverEndpoint = Host.Current.TryGetAsWebDriverEndpoint();

```
        if(webDriverEndpoint == null)
            Report.Info("Selenium", "Test is currently not running on a selenium Endpoint");
        else
        {
                    //Your code here
```

}
        }

Answer (score 0):

To run your existing Selenium test suite from within Ranorex refer to [How to Use Ranorex with Existing Selenium Tests](https://www.ranorex.com/blog/using-ranorex-with-existing-selenium-tests/).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the solution you are providing?

Comment: Actually I've linked a step by step guide which explains how to use your existing selenium test in Ranorex Studio

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. This article describes how to run existing selenium testcases. What I'am looking for is to write small code modules based on selenium syntax and selenium page objects as code modules that ca be then stitched together in ranorex to form a testcase.